# NSString pattern search

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

I want to search for a specific value in a NSString.

```
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="one" VALUE="getthisvalue">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="two" VALUE="getthisvalue">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="three" VALUE="getthisvalue">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="four" VALUE="getthisvalue">
```

I need to obtain the "getthisvalue" in the above code. I was thinking about using a scanner.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `NSRegularExpression`, perhaps? Or if `NSScanner`, then what do you have already?

Comment: regex, scanner are great classes to find. Or you can use simple string and array manipulation, seperatedByString:@"=" will give you getthisvalue at last index. then truncate " from index 0 and store till length-2 (discard ">).

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, I managed to get it working with the scanner class. I scanned from name to value till the end of line :)

Comment: @richardolt If you have solved your own question it is okay to post the answer and accept it. In fact [it's encouraged to do so.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next method (Attention: Using ARC):

```
-(NSMutableArray*)scanInString:(NSString*)string beforeValue:(NSString*)beforeValue afterValue:(NSString*)afterValue{
    NSMutableArray *foundedResults = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSString *allString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];
    BOOL isHavingValue = NO;
    do{
        NSRange beforeRange = [allString rangeOfString:beforeValue];
        if(beforeRange.location != NSNotFound){
            int beforePos = beforeRange.location + beforeRange.length;
            allString = [allString substringFromIndex:beforePos];
            NSRange afterRange = [allString rangeOfString:afterValue];
            if(afterRange.location != NSNotFound){
                isHavingValue = YES;
                int afterPos = afterRange.location;
                NSRange valueRange = NSMakeRange(0, afterPos);
                NSString *value = [allString substringWithRange:valueRange];
                if(value){
                    [foundedResults addObject:value];
                }
            }
            else{
                isHavingValue = NO;
            }
        }
        else{
            isHavingValue = NO;
        }
    }while (isHavingValue);
    return foundedResults;
}
```

Calling:

```
NSString *string = @"<INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"one\" VALUE=\"getthisvalue\"><INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"two\" VALUE=\"ILYA2606\"><INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"three\" VALUE=\"XXX\"><INPUT TYPE=\"HIDDEN\" NAME=\"four\" VALUE=\"getthisvalue\">";
NSLog(@"results = %@", [self scanInString:string beforeValue:@"VALUE=\"" afterValue:@"\""]);
```